# Converting Cursor Based SQL to SET Based Operations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently this SQL takes around 1.5 Hrs to run. I am trying to remove Cursors ( using CTE and recursion ) but I am not able find a suitable solution as this has date based Running totals. Also data is added deleted within cursors

As you can see in the code We have two Cursors one within another. there are 40K records in first cursor. Any Ideas how can this be improved.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @chg_type AS char(4);
DECLARE @chg_date AS datetime;
DECLARE @Salary AS char(9);
DECLARE @chg_factor AS numeric(13, 6);
DECLARE @to_Salary AS char(9);
DECLARE @Salary_permid AS char(9);
DECLARE @to_Salary_permid AS char(9);
DECLARE @income AS int;
DECLARE @cost AS numeric(13, 0);
DECLARE @ReportDate AS datetime;
DECLARE @lagDate AS datetime;
DECLARE @na AS numeric(18, 2);
DECLARE @system_date AS datetime;
DECLARE @count1 AS int;
DECLARE @counter AS int = 0;
SET @system_date = GETDATE();

DROP TABLE #Temptable_ReportDate
CREATE TABLE #Temptable_ReportDate (
     income int,
     Salary char(9),
     cost numeric(13, 0),
     ReportDate datetime
);
DROP TABLE #Temptable_LagDate
CREATE TABLE #Temptable_LagDate (
     income int,
     Salary char(9),
     cost numeric(13, 0),
     lagDate datetime
);
DROP TABLE #cc
CREATE TABLE #cc (
     chg_type char(4),
     chg_date datetime,
     Salary char(9),
     chg_factor numeric(13, 6),
     to_Salary char(9)
);
CREATE INDEX idx_c_ReportDate_income ON #Temptable_ReportDate (income)
CREATE INDEX idx_c_ReportDate_Salary ON #Temptable_ReportDate (Salary)
CREATE INDEX idx_c_lagDate_income ON #Temptable_LagDate (income)
CREATE INDEX idx_c_lagDate_Salary ON #Temptable_LagDate (Salary)
--Delete from #Temptable_ReportDate; 
--insert into #Temptable_ReportDate 
-- SELECT salaryHistory.income, salaryHistory.Salary, salaryHistory.cost, 
--   salaryHistory.ReportDate 
--  FROM 
--      dbo.salaryHistory salaryHistory 
--   inner join salaryMaster_full_view p on p.income = salaryHistory.income and p.ReportDate  = salaryHistory.ReportDate
--  ORDER BY salaryHistory.Salary
DECLARE salaryMaster_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
     income,
     ReportDate,
     lagDate
FROM salaryMaster_full_view
WHERE ReportDate < @system_date
OR lagDate < @system_date
ORDER BY income
OPEN salaryMaster_cursor
BEGIN
     FETCH NEXT
     FROM salaryMaster_cursor
     INTO @income,
     @ReportDate,
     @lagDate
     WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
     BEGIN
          SET @counter = @counter + 1;
          PRINT @counter;
          DELETE FROM #Temptable_ReportDate;
          DELETE FROM #Temptable_LagDate;
          INSERT INTO #Temptable_ReportDate
               SELECT
                    salaryHistory.income,
                    salaryHistory.Salary,
                    salaryHistory.cost,
                    salaryHistory.ReportDate
               FROM dbo.salaryHistory salaryHistory
               WHERE salaryHistory.income = @income
               AND salaryHistory.ReportDate = @ReportDate
               ORDER BY salaryHistory.Salary
          INSERT INTO #Temptable_LagDate
               SELECT
                    salaryHistory.income,
                    salaryHistory.Salary,
                    salaryHistory.cost,
                    salaryHistory.ReportDate
               FROM dbo.salaryHistory salaryHistory
               WHERE salaryHistory.income = @income
               AND salaryHistory.ReportDate = @lagDate
               ORDER BY salaryHistory.Salary
          --select * from #Temptable_ReportDate 
          IF @ReportDate < @system_date
          BEGIN
               DELETE FROM #cc;
               WITH hh_cte
               AS (SELECT
                    c.Salary,
                    c.chg_date,
                    c.to_Salary
               FROM SalaryChange c
               INNER JOIN #Temptable_ReportDate hh
                    ON hh.Salary = c.Salary
               --inner join salaryMaster p on hh.income = p.income and p.ReportDate = hh.ReportDate
               WHERE c.chg_type <> ('SUN')
               AND hh.income = @income
               -- and c.Salary = '204412100' 
               AND NOT (
               c.chg_type IN ('MON',
               'TUE',
               'WED')
               AND chg_factor = 0)
               AND chg_date > hh.ReportDate
               AND chg_date < @system_date),
               cap_change_cte
               AS (SELECT
                    c.*
               FROM hh_cte c
               UNION ALL
               SELECT
                    c.Salary,
                    c.chg_date,
                    c.to_Salary
               FROM SalaryChange c
               INNER JOIN cap_change_cte cc
                    ON cc.to_Salary = c.Salary
               --and c.to_Salary!= c.Salary 
               WHERE c.chg_type <> ('SUN')
               AND NOT (
               c.chg_type IN ('MON',
               'TUE',
               'WED')
               AND c.chg_factor = 0)
               -- AND c.chg_date > cc.ReportDate 
               AND c.chg_date < @system_date
               AND cc.chg_date < c.chg_date)
               INSERT INTO #cc
                    SELECT
                         chg_type,
                         chg_date,
                         Salary,
                         chg_factor,
                         to_Salary
                    FROM SalaryChange
                    WHERE Salary IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                         cc.Salary
                    FROM cap_change_cte cc)
               DECLARE salary_changes CURSOR FOR
               SELECT
                    cc.chg_type,
                    cc.chg_date,
                    cc.Salary,
                    cc.chg_factor,
                    cc.to_Salary
               FROM #cc cc
               ORDER BY cc.chg_date,
               cc.Salary;

               OPEN salary_changes
               FETCH NEXT
               FROM salary_changes
               INTO @chg_type,
               @chg_date,
               @Salary,
               @chg_factor,
               @to_Salary
               WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
               BEGIN
                    SET @count1 = (SELECT
                         COUNT(*)
                    FROM #Temptable_ReportDate
                    WHERE income = @income
                    AND Salary = @Salary);
                    IF (@count1 > 0)
                    BEGIN

                         DECLARE @newcost AS numeric(13, 0);
                         DECLARE @count AS int;
                         SET @newcost = ROUND(@cost * @chg_factor, 0);
                         IF @chg_type IN ('MON',
                              'TUE')
                         BEGIN
                              SET @count = (SELECT
                                   COUNT(*)
                              FROM #Temptable_ReportDate
                              WHERE income = @income
                              AND Salary = @to_Salary);
                              IF (@count > 0)
                                   UPDATE #Temptable_ReportDate
                                   SET cost = cost + @newcost,
                                       Salary = @to_Salary
                                   WHERE income = @income
                                   AND Salary = @Salary;

                              ELSE
                                   INSERT INTO #Temptable_ReportDate
                                        VALUES (@income, @to_Salary, @newcost, @ReportDate);

                         END
                         ELSE
                         BEGIN
                              IF @Salary = @to_Salary
                                   UPDATE #Temptable_ReportDate
                                   SET cost = @newcost
                                   WHERE income = @income
                                   AND Salary = @Salary
                              ELSE
                              BEGIN
                                   SET @count = (SELECT
                                        COUNT(*)
                                   FROM #Temptable_ReportDate
                                   WHERE income = @income
                                   AND Salary = @to_Salary);
                                   IF (@count > 0)
                                   BEGIN
                                        UPDATE #Temptable_ReportDate
                                        SET cost = cost + @newcost
                                        FROM #Temptable_ReportDate
                                        WHERE income = @income
                                        AND Salary = @to_Salary
                                        DELETE FROM #Temptable_ReportDate
                                        WHERE income = @income
                                             AND Salary = @Salary;

                                   END
                                   ELSE
                                        UPDATE #Temptable_ReportDate
                                        SET cost = @newcost,
                                            Salary = @to_Salary
                                        WHERE income = @income
                                        AND Salary = @Salary;

                              END
                         END
                    END
                    FETCH NEXT
                    FROM salary_changes
                    INTO @chg_type,
                    @chg_date,
                    @Salary,
                    @chg_factor,
                    @to_Salary
               END
               CLOSE salary_changes
               DEALLOCATE salary_changes
          END
          IF @lagDate < @system_date
          BEGIN
               DELETE FROM #cc;

               WITH hh_cte
               AS (SELECT
                    c.*
               FROM SalaryChange c
               INNER JOIN #Temptable_LagDate hh
                    ON hh.Salary = c.Salary
               --inner join salaryMaster p on hh.income = p.income and p.ReportDate = hh.ReportDate 
               WHERE c.chg_type <> ('SUN')
               AND hh.income = @income
               -- and c.Salary = '204412100' 
               AND NOT (
               c.chg_type IN ('MON',
               'TUE',
               'WED')
               AND chg_factor = 0)
               AND chg_date > hh.lagDate
               AND chg_date < @system_date),
               cap_change_cte
               AS (SELECT
                    c.*
               FROM hh_cte c
               UNION ALL
               SELECT
                    c.*
               FROM SalaryChange c
               INNER JOIN cap_change_cte cc
                    ON cc.to_Salary = c.Salary
               --and c.to_Salary!= c.Salary 
               WHERE c.chg_type <> ('SUN')
               AND NOT (
               c.chg_type IN ('MON',
               'TUE',
               'WED')
               AND c.chg_factor = 0)
               -- AND c.chg_date > cc.ReportDate 
               AND c.chg_date < @system_date
               AND cc.chg_date < c.chg_date)
               INSERT INTO #cc
                    SELECT
                         chg_type,
                         chg_date,
                         Salary,
                         chg_factor,
                         to_Salary
                    FROM SalaryChange
                    WHERE Salary IN (SELECT
                         cc.Salary
                    FROM cap_change_cte cc)
               DECLARE salary_changes CURSOR FOR
               SELECT
                    cc.chg_type,
                    cc.chg_date,
                    cc.Salary,
                    cc.chg_factor,
                    cc.to_Salary
               FROM #cc cc
               ORDER BY cc.chg_date,
               cc.Salary;

               OPEN salary_changes
               FETCH NEXT
               FROM salary_changes
               INTO @chg_type,
               @chg_date,
               @Salary,
               @chg_factor,
               @to_Salary
               WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
               BEGIN
                    SET @count1 = (SELECT
                         COUNT(*)
                    FROM #Temptable_LagDate
                    WHERE income = @income
                    AND Salary = @Salary);
                    IF (@count1 > 0)
                    BEGIN
                         SET @newcost = ROUND(@cost * @chg_factor, 0);
                         IF @chg_type IN ('MON',
                              'TUE')
                         BEGIN
                              SET @count = (SELECT
                                   COUNT(*)
                              FROM #Temptable_LagDate
                              WHERE income = @income
                              AND Salary = @to_Salary);
                              IF (@count > 0)
                                   UPDATE #Temptable_LagDate
                                   SET cost = cost + @newcost,
                                       Salary = @to_Salary
                                   WHERE income = @income
                                   AND Salary = @Salary;

                              ELSE
                                   INSERT INTO #Temptable_LagDate
                                        VALUES (@income, @to_Salary, @newcost, @lagDate);

                         END
                         ELSE
                         BEGIN
                              IF @Salary = @to_Salary
                                   UPDATE #Temptable_LagDate
                                   SET cost = @newcost
                                   WHERE income = @income
                                   AND Salary = @Salary
                              ELSE
                              BEGIN
                                   SET @count = (SELECT
                                        COUNT(*)
                                   FROM #Temptable_LagDate
                                   WHERE income = @income
                                   AND Salary = @to_Salary);
                                   IF (@count > 0)
                                   BEGIN
                                        UPDATE #Temptable_LagDate
                                        SET cost = cost + @newcost
                                        FROM #Temptable_LagDate
                                        WHERE income = @income
                                        AND Salary = @to_Salary
                                        DELETE FROM #Temptable_LagDate
                                        WHERE income = @income
                                             AND Salary = @Salary;

                                   END
                                   ELSE
                                        UPDATE #Temptable_LagDate
                                        SET cost = @newcost,
                                            Salary = @to_Salary
                                        WHERE income = @income
                                        AND Salary = @Salary;

                              END
                         END
                    END
                    FETCH NEXT
                    FROM salary_changes
                    INTO @chg_type,
                    @chg_date,
                    @Salary,
                    @chg_factor,
                    @to_Salary
               END
               CLOSE salary_changes
               DEALLOCATE salary_changes
          END;


          --select * from #Temptable_ReportDate;
          --select * from #Temptable_LagDate;
          INSERT INTO salary_current_test (income, Salary, cost, na, cost_change, change_na, ReportDate, lagDate, cost_date, hold, release, change)
               SELECT
                    ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.income, #Temptable_LagDate.income) AS income,
                    ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.Salary, #Temptable_LagDate.Salary) AS Salary,
                    SUM(ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.cost, 0)) AS cost,
                    ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.cost, 0) * 0 AS na,
                    SUM(ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.cost, 0) - ISNULL(#Temptable_LagDate.cost, 0)) AS cost_change,
                    ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.cost, 0) * 0 AS change_na,
                    ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.ReportDate, @ReportDate) AS ReportDate,
                    ISNULL(#Temptable_LagDate.lagDate, @lagDate) AS lagDate,
                    GETDATE() AS cost_date,
                    0 AS hold,
                    0 AS release,
                    1 AS change
               FROM #Temptable_ReportDate
               FULL OUTER JOIN #Temptable_LagDate
                    ON #Temptable_ReportDate.Salary = #Temptable_LagDate.Salary
               GROUP BY ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.income, #Temptable_LagDate.income),
                        ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.Salary, #Temptable_LagDate.Salary),
                        ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.cost, 0) * 0,
                        ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.cost, 0) * 0,
                        ISNULL(#Temptable_ReportDate.ReportDate, @ReportDate),
                        ISNULL(#Temptable_LagDate.lagDate, @lagDate)
               ORDER BY 2

          FETCH NEXT
          FROM salaryMaster_cursor
          INTO @income,
          @ReportDate,
          @lagDate
     END
END
CLOSE salaryMaster_cursor
DEALLOCATE salaryMaster_cursor
SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Comment: Holy crap... First, I think you might get a better response over at [codereview.se], or maybe [dba.se].  Second, I'm pretty sure that even they would balk at the amount of code you expect us to wade through.  You should cut that down into bite size pieces.

Comment: I once replaced a cursor-based solution for date-based running totals with a set-based solution.  It was a work of art, and when I ran it, it was slower than the cursor-based solution.   Sometimes cursors are better.   That said, you might get faster performance with a CLR solution.

Comment: Well It used to take 5+hrs to run :) And I was slowly improving this and now it takes around 1.5Hrs to run. I just came to a Dead End. This is just a part of the code will see if I can simplify it further. When you say CLR solution does it mean I should try to convert it into C# or something

Comment: Sort of.   CLR lets you run code that has been compiled into the CLR in SQL server.  You don't have to create the C# in a different environment.  It's all done in SSMS.

Comment: I doubt your going to get better performance changing it to set-based, and a fuller understanding of the schema, and existing indexes would be necessary.  Have you profiled it to find out what your pain points for performance are?  In many cases it is just one of the conditions or SQL statements within the cursors that is causing the problem.